# Como puedo reparar este error de pip al instalar pip install mod-wsgi

Tags: python, pip

Hola Tengo un problema al instalar install mod-wsgi en windows 10 siempre que me intica este error:

```
Collecting mod_wsgi
Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/25/d8/1df4ba9c051cd88e02971814f0867274a8ac821baf983b6778dacd6e31f7/mod_wsgi-4.6.8.tar.gz
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
command: 'c:\users\usppdata\local\programs\python\python37\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\Users\USSOPO~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-bqhfkp4y\mod-wsgi\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\Users\US~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-bqhfkp4y\mod-wsgi\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'
'"'"', '"'"'
'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base pip-egg-info
cwd: C:\Users\USSOPO~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-bqhfkp4y\mod-wsgi\
Complete output (5 lines):
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
File "C:\Users\USSOPO~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-bqhfkp4y\mod-wsgi\setup.py", line 158, in <module>
raise RuntimeError('No Apache installation can be found. Set the '
RuntimeError: No Apache installation can be found. Set the MOD_WSGI_APACHE_ROOTDIR environment to its location.
----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

y tengo apache instalado

Comment: Veo que te está pidiendo que des un valor a la variable de entorno `MOD_WSGI_APACHE_ROOTDIR` indicando la ruta hacia la carpeta en que tienes instalado Apache. Por ejemplo `set MOD_WSGI_APACHE_ROOTDIR=F:\Apache25`

Comment: C:\\Users\\USSOPO~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-3fwzj4v1\\mod-wsgi\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\USSOPO~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-k4dfplmy\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\sokecsito\sock\include\site\python3.7\mod-wsgi' Check the logs for full command output.

Comment: Ahora me sale eso

Comment: Actualiza tu pregunta y pon el error completo para poder ayudarte

Comment: el mod_wsgi es del servidor (ahora @abulafia me dice algo pythonico)

Answer (score 0):

Verifica también si en la lista de errores que obtienes hay una linea de error que diga algo similar a 'WARNING: The wheel package is not available.'
En ese caso, instala cada paquete faltante por separado y vuelve a intentarlo. Generalmente esto resuelve el problema.

Comment: Estás en SO. En español por favor procura responder en dicho idioma

Comment: ya he resuleto el problema pero gracias